# how to draw a very short line with actionscript?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I am having trouble drawing a very short line with actionscript3:

```
var cSp:Sprite = new Sprite();
var cGx:Graphics = cSp.graphics;
cGx.lineStyle( 1, 0xFF0000, 1, false, LineScaleMode.NONE, null, null, 1 );

cGx.moveTo( 2, 10 );
cGx.lineTo( 3, 10 );
```

This creates two *vertically stacked* pixels which are not quite red (#7f0000)!

[vertical line? http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/449212bd1f.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/449212bd1f.png)

*(here it is zoomed in:)*

[zoomed in http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/5c9014a148.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/5c9014a148.png)

Since I am trying to draw a horizontal line, this is not what I expected.  I assume there is some alias/sub-pixel trickery going on here.  What's the magic combination of commands to draw a really short line or one pixel?

Note: if I make my really short line 4 pixels (or more) long, it is rendered as expected (4+ pixels long, 1 pixel tall, every rendered pixel #FF0000)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try playing with the various *caps* and *joints* settings? Your values of null/null would direct Flash to use round caps and round joints. Your [last] parameter of "1" for the *miter limit* would also be ignored as you wouldn't be using miter joints.

I would suggest trying CapsStyle.NONE first. Then maybe miter joints. For reference: [Graphics.lineStyle()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#lineStyle%28%29).

Edit: Try using *pixel hinting*, too.

Comment: thanks.  enumerated all the possibilities, and this does the trick.
lineStyle( 1, 0xFF0000, 1, true, null, CapsStyle.SQUARE);

Comment: I'm glad it helped someone even after 20 months :)